# transmission on ubuntu 16.04 LTS write permission problem

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, bittorrent, transmission

I get a problem with my Transmission 2.94 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server. I used [this guide to install Transmission](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo).

- I tried different dir on my disks and all give me same problem.
- I tried reinstall and that didn't help.
- I tried to edit `sudo nano /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` with no help and working on user groups.

On this cmd is this correct?

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission myuser
```

Now I don’t know what to do.

[image: problem indicator]

I did edit the path after the picture was taken.

```
Permission denied (/home/thomas/media/hdd2/ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64.iso)
```

still same problem

When connected to SMB and download with utorrent on windows to Ubuntu path it is successful.

edit:

```
thomas@ubuntu:~$ command ls -ld /home/thomas/media/hdd2{,/ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64.iso}
ls: cannot access '/home/thomas/media/hdd2/ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64.iso': No such file or directory
drwxrwsr-x 4 thomas thomas 4096 Jul 18 18:20 /home/thomas/media/hdd2
thomas@ubuntu:~$
```

Edit:

i did tried to edit /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon and set the user to "root" this also gives me error

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `command ls -ld /home/thomas/media/hdd2{,/ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64.iso}`? Thanks.

Comment: In case this is a mountpoint: `/home/thomas/media/hdd2/:  You can't use a windows partition for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cmd you wrote is gonna add your user to the `debian-transmission` group. That's correct. However, you need to log out and log back to apply this setting, maybe that's where it went wrong.

Maybe there's a simple folder permission. If it's what I think, here's what you need to do:

(EDIT: new directories)

- change group ownership of the download folder:

  `$ sudo chgrp -R debian-transmission /media/hdd2/tv`
- grant write access for group members:

  `$ sudo chmod -R 770 /media/hdd2/tv`
- In `settings.json`, change the path of the download folder:

  `"download-dir": "/media/hdd2/tv",`
- Restart the deamon:

  `$ sudo service transmission-daemon stop`

  `$ sudo service transmission-daemon start`

Comment: every time i change something i usergroups i do a reboot just to be sure

Comment: the problem did come back after i did delete the download and tried again so it was a 2min fix

Comment: Is there a temporary download folder like download-incomplete? What is the output of the following command: `ls -l /home/thomas/media/hdd2/`. Maybe also add the `settings.json` file to your original post, there might me something wrong here.

Comment: now i did change the folder to /media/hdd2/tv hoping that would change someting but no luck.

Comment: `settings.json` shows that `"download-dir": "/media"`. Set this value to the correct path.

Comment: ls -l /media/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root 4096 Jul 19 21:22 cdrom
drwxrwsr-x 4 thomas  123 4096 Jul 17 21:01 hdd1
drwxrwsr-x 4 thomas  123 4096 Jul 19 21:06 hdd2
drwxrwsr-x 5 thomas  123 4096 Jul 19 14:27 hdd3

Comment: dont understand why its thomas:123 on path's and under sub directions

Comment: Those are your external partitions mount points. This is normal, but not what I asked for. Your path is: `/media/hdd2/tv`. What are the permissions for it? `ls -l /media/hdd2/`.

Comment: ls -l /media/hdd2/
total 20
drwxrwsr-x 2 thomas thomas 16384 Jul 17 19:44 lost+found
drwxr-sr-x 2 thomas thomas  4096 Jul 20 10:02 tv

Comment: Ok, I updated my post with the correct path. Follow my instructions and it should work.

Comment: thanks alot... :D for now its working even if i sub path under /media/hdd2/tv/fantasy for example

Comment: Yes that's why I added the `-R` option, to apply permissions to subdirectories (recursively)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"alt-speed-down": 50,
"alt-speed-enabled": false,
"alt-speed-time-begin": 540,
"alt-speed-time-day": 127,
"alt-speed-time-enabled": false,
"alt-speed-time-end": 1020,
"alt-speed-up": 50,
"bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
"bind-address-ipv6": "::",
"blocklist-enabled": false,
"blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist",
"cache-size-mb": 4,
"dht-enabled": true,
"download-dir": "/media",
"download-limit": 100,
"download-limit-enabled": 0,
"download-queue-enabled": true,
"download-queue-size": 5,
"encryption": 1,
"idle-seeding-limit": 30,
"idle-seeding-limit-enabled": false,
"incomplete-dir": "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/Downloads",
"incomplete-dir-enabled": false,
"lpd-enabled": false,
"max-peers-global": 200,
"message-level": 1,
"peer-congestion-algorithm": "",
"peer-id-ttl-hours": 6,
"peer-limit-global": 200,
"peer-limit-per-torrent": 50,
"peer-port": 51413,
"peer-port-random-high": 65535,
"peer-port-random-low": 49152,
"peer-port-random-on-start": false,
"peer-socket-tos": "default",
"pex-enabled": true,
"port-forwarding-enabled": false,
"preallocation": 1,
"prefetch-enabled": true,
"queue-stalled-enabled": true,
"queue-stalled-minutes": 30,
"ratio-limit": 2,
"ratio-limit-enabled": false,
"rename-partial-files": true,
"rpc-authentication-required": true,
"rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0",
"rpc-enabled": true,
"rpc-host-whitelist": "",
"rpc-host-whitelist-enabled": true,
"rpc-password": "{018b0d1476c793d3b8a88Vppg",
"rpc-port": 9091,
"rpc-url": "/transmission/",
"rpc-username": "thomas",
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192.168.*.*",
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,
"scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true,
"script-torrent-done-enabled": false,
"script-torrent-done-filename": "",
"seed-queue-enabled": false,
"seed-queue-size": 10,
"speed-limit-down": 100,
"speed-limit-down-enabled": false,
"speed-limit-up": 100,
"speed-limit-up-enabled": false,
"start-added-torrents": true,
"trash-original-torrent-files": false,
"umask": 2,
"upload-limit": 100,
"upload-limit-enabled": 0,
"upload-slots-per-torrent": 14,
"utp-enabled": true
```

}